# Delete group if NaN is present anywhere in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean my dataframe such that if my "Base_2007" and "Base_2011" column contains NA, then I should completely drop that county. In my case since both Counties contains NA both of them will be dropped. Thus empty dataset will be returned. Is it possible to do something like this?

Data:

```
  State  Year  Base_2007  Base_2011           County
0    AL  2012        NaN       14.0  Alabama_Country
1    AL  2013       12.0       20.0  Alabama_Country
2    AL  2014       13.0        NaN  Alabama_Country
3    DC  2011        NaN       20.0          Trenton
4    DC  2012       19.0        NaN          Trenton
5    DC  2013       20.0       21.0          Trenton
6    DC  2014       25.0       30.0          Trenton
```

Tail section of dataframe:

```
{'State': {82550: 'WY', 82551: 'WY', 82552: 'WY', 82553: 'WY', 82554: 'WY', 82555: 'WY', 82556: 'WY', 82557: 'WY', 82558: 'WY', 82559: 'WY'}, 'County': {82550: 'Weston', 82551: 'Weston', 82552: 'Weston', 82553: 'Weston', 82554: 'Weston', 82555: 'Weston', 82556: 'Weston', 82557: 'Weston', 82558: 'Weston', 82559: 'Weston'}, 'FIPS code': {82550: 56045, 82551: 56045, 82552: 56045, 82553: 56045, 82554: 56045, 82555: 56045, 82556: 56045, 82557: 56045, 82558: 56045, 82559: 56045}, 'Year': {82550: 2008, 82551: 2009, 82552: 2010, 82553: 2011, 82554: 2012, 82555: 2013, 82556: 2014, 82557: 2015, 82558: 2016, 82559: 2017}, 'Annual_pct_change': {82550: 6.52, 82551: -2.93, 82552: -5.61, 82553: 1.9, 82554: 5.16, 82555: -4.03, 82556: 7.69, 82557: -2.35, 82558: 1.67, 82559: 5.56}, 'HPI': {82550: 195.73, 82551: 189.99, 82552: 179.33, 82553: 182.73, 82554: 192.15, 82555: 184.4, 82556: 198.58, 82557: 193.9, 82558: 197.14, 82559: 208.11}, 'HPI1990': {82550: nan, 82551: nan, 82552: nan, 82553: nan, 82554: nan, 82555: nan, 82556: nan, 82557: nan, 82558: nan, 82559: nan}, 'HPI2000': {82550: 190.09, 82551: 184.51, 82552: 174.16, 82553: 177.46, 82554: 186.61, 82555: 179.08, 82556: 192.86, 82557: 188.31, 82558: 191.46, 82559: 202.11}, 'CountyName': {82550: 'Weston County', 82551: 'Weston County', 82552: 'Weston County', 82553: 'Weston County', 82554: 'Weston County', 82555: 'Weston County', 82556: 'Weston County', 82557: 'Weston County', 82558: 'Weston County', 82559: 'Weston County'}}
```

Head Section of DataFrame:

```
{'State': {0: 'AL', 1: 'AL', 2: 'AL', 3: 'AL', 4: 'AL', 5: 'AL', 6: 'AL', 7: 'AL', 8: 'AL', 9: 'AL'}, 'County': {0: 'Autauga', 1: 'Autauga', 2: 'Autauga', 3: 'Autauga', 4: 'Autauga', 5: 'Autauga', 6: 'Autauga', 7: 'Autauga', 8: 'Autauga', 9: 'Autauga'}, 'FIPS code': {0: 1001, 1: 1001, 2: 1001, 3: 1001, 4: 1001, 5: 1001, 6: 1001, 7: 1001, 8: 1001, 9: 1001}, 'Year': {0: 1986, 1: 1987, 2: 1988, 3: 1989, 4: 1990, 5: 1991, 6: 1992, 7: 1993, 8: 1994, 9: 1995}, 'Annual_pct_change': {0: nan, 1: -2.17, 2: 3.24, 3: 4.16, 4: -0.35, 5: 2.69, 6: 2.85, 7: 3.34, 8: 4.33, 9: 3.48}, 'HPI': {0: 100.0, 1: 97.83, 2: 100.99, 3: 105.19, 4: 104.82, 5: 107.64, 6: 110.7, 7: 114.4, 8: 119.35, 9: 123.5}, 'HPI1990': {0: 95.4, 1: 93.33, 2: 96.35, 3: 100.36, 4: 100.0, 5: 102.69, 6: 105.61, 7: 109.14, 8: 113.86, 9: 117.82}, 'HPI2000': {0: 71.03, 1: 69.49, 2: 71.74, 3: 74.72, 4: 74.45, 5: 76.46, 6: 78.63, 7: 81.26, 8: 84.77, 9: 87.72}, 'CountyName': {0: 'Autauga County', 1: 'Autauga County', 2: 'Autauga County', 3: 'Autauga County', 4: 'Autauga County', 5: 'Autauga County', 6: 'Autauga County', 7: 'Autauga County', 8: 'Autauga County', 9: 'Autauga County'}}
```

Note: In above `dput` Base_2007= HPI1990, BASE_2011=HPI2000

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tested this on the below dataset *(this also requires the `NA` to be replaced by `np.nan` as `df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)` if they are strings)*

```
print(df)

  State  Year  Base_2007  Base_2011           County
0    AL  2012        NaN       14.0  Alabama_Country
1    AL  2013       12.0       20.0  Alabama_Country
2    AL  2014       13.0        NaN  Alabama_Country
3    DC  2011        NaN       20.0          Trenton
4    DC  2012       19.0        NaN          Trenton
5    DC  2013       20.0       21.0          Trenton
6    DC  2014       25.0       30.0          Trenton
7    DM  2013       34.0       45.0            Dummy
8    DM  2012       34.0       45.0            Dummy
```

Removing `County` containing NaN works by using :

```
df_new=df.loc[~df.County.isin(df.loc[df[['Base_2007','Base_2011']].isna().\
                                        any(axis=1),'County'])]
print(df_new)

  State  Year  Base_2007  Base_2011 County
7    DM  2013       34.0       45.0  Dummy
8    DM  2012       34.0       45.0  Dummy
```

I will update the explanation shortly.

**Explanation**

> > The following finds any NaN rows based on subset of `Base_2007` and `Base_2011`

```
df[['Base_2007','Base_2011']].isna().any(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
```

Taking the above output as a boolean mask , we call the [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) function as:

```
df.loc[df[['Base_2007','Base_2011']].isna().any(axis=1),'County']
```

which gives:

```
0    Alabama_Country
2    Alabama_Country
3            Trenton
4            Trenton
```

*Note* we are taking only the `County` column under **`df.loc[]**`. the reason for this is the next step.

We take the output above and find if any of cells in `County` column from the original dataframe exists in the output we got above by using [`s.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin)

This returns True for rows in `County` which is present in the output of `df.loc[]`.

Then we negate them by an invert `~` which turns all `True` to `False` and vice versa.

```
~df.County.isin(df.loc[df[['Base_2007','Base_2011']].isna().any(axis=1),'County'])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
```

Once we have this ready, we apply the same logic as `df.loc[]` .

Finally we get the dataframe which returns only those County which doesnot have a NaN in `Base_2007` and  `Base_2011`.

**Note** : if we want the index to start from 0 and not the slice of the dataframe, we can add a `reset_index(drop=True)` to the end of the code as:

```
df_new=df.loc[~df.County.isin(df.loc[df[['Base_2007','Base_2011']].isna().\                                 
                    any(axis=1),'County'])].reset_index(drop=True)

   State  Year  Base_2007  Base_2011 County
0    DM  2013       34.0       45.0  Dummy
1    DM  2012       34.0       45.0  Dummy
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `query` in pandas checking null and finding `unique` county

```
county = data.query("Base_2011.isnull() or Base_2007.isnull()", engine='python').County.unique()
```

select all the row with remaining county from the list

```
data[~data.County.isin(county)]
```

```
State   Year    Base_2007   Base_2011   County
7   DM  2013    34.0    45.0    Dummy
8   DM  2012    34.0    45.0    Dummy
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the Nan by using

```
    df.dropna()
```

---

```
            State  Year  Base_2007  Base_2011           County
          1    AL  2013       12.0       20.0  Alabama_Country
          5    DC  2013       20.0       21.0          Trenton
          6    DC  2014       25.0       30.0          Trenton
          7    DM  2013       34.0       45.0            Dummy
          8    DM  2012       34.0       45.0            Dummy
```

Comment: This does not have the desired effect of dropping the entire group, i.e. the remaining Alabama and Trenton rows should also be dropped.